# PHP /DAO / MYSQL Year range

Tags: php, mysql

Ok now
i have function

```
public function getCarAttr()
    {
        $this->dao->select();
        $this->dao->from( $this->getTable_CarAttr());
      //$this->dao->where('fk_i_item_id', $itemId);
      $this->dao->groupBy('i_year', 'ASC') ;

        $result = $this->dao->get();
        if( !$result ) {
            return array() ;
        }

        return $result->result();
    }
```

and from fields like:

```
<div class="row one_input">
    <h6><?php _e('Year', 'cars_attributes'); ?></h6>
    <select name="year" id="year">
        <option value=""><?php _e('From', 'cars_attributes'); ?></option>
        <?php foreach($years as $y) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $y['fk_i_item_id']; ?>" <?php if($year==$y['fk_i_item_id']) { echo 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $y['i_year']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <select name="year" id="year">
        <option value=""><?php _e('To', 'cars_attributes'); ?></option>
        <?php foreach($years as $y) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $y['fk_i_item_id']; ?>" <?php if($year==$y['fk_i_item_id']) { echo 'selected'; } ?>><?php echo $y['i_year']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

And then:

```
    // self-explanatory
function cars_item_detail() {
    if( osc_is_this_category('cars_plugin', osc_item_category_id()) ) {
        $detail   = ModelCars::newInstance()->getCarAttr(osc_item_id()) ;

        if( count($detail) == 0 ) {
            return ;
        }

        $make     = ModelCars::newInstance()->getCarMakeById( $detail['fk_i_make_id'] );
        $model    = ModelCars::newInstance()->getCarModelById( $detail['fk_i_model_id'] );
        $car_type = ModelCars::newInstance()->getVehicleTypeById($detail['fk_vehicle_type_id']);
        $year = ModelCars::newInstance()->getCarAttr($detail['i_year']);

        $detail['s_make'] = '' ;
        if( array_key_exists('s_name', $make) ) {
            $detail['s_make']  = $make['s_name'];
        }
        $detail['s_model'] = '' ;
        if( array_key_exists('s_name', $model) ) {
            $detail['s_model']  = $model['s_name'];
        }
        $detail['locale']  = array() ;
        foreach($car_type as $c) {
            $detail['locale'][$c['fk_c_locale_code']]['s_car_type'] = $c['s_name'] ;
        }
        $detail['i_year'] = '' ;
        if( array_key_exists('i_year', $model) ) {
            $detail['i_year']  = $model['i_year'];
        }
        require_once 'item_detail.php' ;
    }
}

    // Adds some plugin-specific search conditions
function cars_search_conditions($params) {
    // we need conditions and search tables (only if we're using our custom tables)
    $has_conditions = false ;
    foreach($params as $key => $value) {
        // we may want to have param-specific searches
        switch($key) {
            case 'type':
                if( is_numeric($value) ) {
                    Search::newInstance()->addConditions(sprintf("%st_item_car_attr.fk_vehicle_type_id = %d", DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $value));
                    $has_conditions = true;
                }
            break;
            case 'make':
                if( is_numeric($value) ) {
                    Search::newInstance()->addConditions(sprintf("%st_item_car_attr.fk_i_make_id = %d", DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $value));
                    $has_conditions = true;
                }
            break;
            case 'model':
                if( is_numeric($value) ) {
                    Search::newInstance()->addConditions(sprintf("%st_item_car_attr.fk_i_model_id = %d", DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $value));
                    $has_conditions = true;
                }
            break;
            case 'year':
                if( is_numeric($value) ) {
                    Search::newInstance()->addConditions(sprintf("%st_item_car_attr.i_year = %d", DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $value));
                    $has_conditions = true;
                }
            break;
            case 'transmission':
                if( $value == 'AUTO' || $value == 'MANUAL' ) {
                    Search::newInstance()->addConditions(sprintf("%st_item_car_attr.e_transmission = '%s'", DB_TABLE_PREFIX, $value));
                    $has_conditions = true;
                }
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Now it's shows me the car production years no problem, 
they sorted from lowest to highest no problem

but my problem is when i pick lets say 2001 and 2003
after click refine button it comes out 2003 and 2003 and system shows "No matching results" any ideas??

Comment: Your select tags have the same ID and name. HTML elements must have unique IDs. Names can be repeated, but since you're using them to filter years by a range, change them to something else, like fromYear and toYear, or whatever.

Comment: I change to f_year and t_year and now after refine it shows me all result and reset it's self to "FROM" & "TO" which is defined as placeholder
I just wondering how to set the function RANGE or more than likely BETWEEN should be ok?

Comment: Any one can help??